# Tattoo on person with hepatitis b

Tags: blood, risks, liver, hepatitis

Is it ok for a person with hepatitis b to get a tattoo? What are the risks? Will it make the condition worse?

Answer (score 4):

A tattoo will be irrelevant to the person with Hep-B receiving it. The risks will be the same as anyone else receiving a tattoo, except of course that Hep-B won't be among those risks as it normally would. It will not make the condition worse.

However, it will present a risk to the tattoo artist and anyone else exposed to the used needles, ink, and other supplies that were exposed to the person's body fluids. Anyone exposed to the tattoo before it has healed will also be at risk.

The person with the disease is the threat, not the other way around.

http://www.who.int/ith/diseases/hepatitisB/en/